# My code for determining whether prime number exist between intervals is flawed

Tags: java

I have been requested by Math Stack Exchange users to immediately ask on this site what is wrong with my program.

I wrote code to determine whether there is a prime within each interval from $n*n$ to $(n+1)*(n+1)$. I was just looking at stuff regarding legendre's conjecture. This was in response to a math stack exchange post asking about it. The code is below:

```
for (int n = 10000; n < 90000; n++)
{
   int m = 0;
   for (int i = n*n; i <= (n+1)*(n+1); i++)
   {
      int k = 0;
      for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++)
      {
         if ((i % j) == 0)
         {
            k+=1;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (k == 0)
      {
         m+=1;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (m == 0)
   {
      System.out.println("The conjecture has been disproven for n = " + String.valueOf(n));
   }
}
```

It spat out the "counter examples" n = 46340 and n = 80264 which the code claims are intervals that fail to contain primes.

Thinking I had somehow disproved the conjecture (I was not aware that it was anything beyond a conjecture made by the asker) I then posted that exact code to that math stack exchange question as an answer showing those counter examples and was told then they were wrong about the conjecture being unsolved. I was told **very** strongly that I was wrong and flat out ordered to go ask on this site why the code is broken. Based on that my code is *somehow* flawed, but nothing stands out to me.

I have no reason to really want this code fixed or anything. I’m just here to satisfy the desires of those wanting to know specifically why my MSE answer was bogus.

Comment: or c) you're overflowing `int`

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Next time try to write a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem instead.  If you had done that for this question, you would have gotten a syntax error when trying to reproduce the issue for `46340` since the compiler will give you a syntax error when you try to write the loop `for (int i = 2147395600; i < 2147488281; i++)`..

Comment: You can consider using apache commons math3 for checking prime instead of doing it yourself, their routines may be faster than the brute force:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your algorithm is correct. However, the data type `int` in Java is not capable to hold numbers that large. Concretely, the maximal value an integer can have is

```
 Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2.147.483.647
```

Interesting enough the choice n = 46340 is *exactly* the smallest n for which your algorithm breaks that barrier, because

```
 n*n               = 2.147.395.600 < Integer.MAX_VALUE,
 (n+1)*(n+1)       = 2.147.488.281 > Integer.MAX_VALUE.
```

As a quick fix, you can use the data type `long` instead, which can store much greater values up until

```
Long.MAX_VALUE     = 9.223.372.036.854.775.807
```

If you want to avoid upper barriers completely, you should take a look at the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class which is designed for precisely that purpose.